# Правильно ли построено предложение?

Tags: грамотная-речь

> Данный социальный проект предполагает
> проведение на территории района
> различных акций: по благоустройству
> заброшенных могил ветеранов войны,
> оказанию помощи участникам войны,
> посадке аллеи памяти.

Мне кажется, что после двоеточия в данном предложении надо написать:

> благоустройство заброшенных могил...,
> оказание помощи..., посадка аллеи
> памяти.

Или все оставить как есть?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно предложить такой вариант:

> Данный социальный проект предполагает
> проведение на территории района таких
> акций, как  благоустройство
> заброшенных могил ветеранов войны,
> оказание помощи участникам войны,
> посадка аллеи памяти.